# "Could find or load main class" while running executable jar file in Java code

Tags: java

After converting my java program to executable jar file using commands in command prompt in windows 10,while executing jar file I am getting error:

> Could find or load main class Combine.class"  caused
>   by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:Combine.class

My jdk-11.0.1 has javamail api and excelapi.While executing I have set my classpath as:

```
classpath=%classpath%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\javamail_api\javax.mail-1.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\javamail_api\activation.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\jexcelapi\jxl.jar;.;
```

It was compiling and executing properly but after converting to executable jar file it is not running and giving above error.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Is your own jar in the classpath ? Also please add the full command line you are using.

Comment: simplest solution, make a runnable jar (it will include everything needed). the issue is that your jar doesn't include those libraries

Comment: echo Main-Class: Combine.class > manifest.txt
jar cmf manifest.txt FinalExecutable.jar  Combine.class I am using these commands to convert into executable file

Comment: View your jar file in archive explorer to debug your mainfest.

Comment: How are you building your JAR?

Comment: Also: don't forget to put the full name of the class, ie with the package if there is any

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the exception message.  It is trying to load a class with the name `Combine.class`.  But the classes real name is `Combine`.

You have created the JAR file incorrectly.

```
 echo Main-Class: Combine.class > manifest.txt 
 jar cmf manifest.txt FinalExecutable.jar Combine.class
```

If `Combine` is in the default package (i.e. it doesn't have a `package` statement) then the above should be:

```
 echo Main-Class: Combine > manifest.txt 
 jar cmf manifest.txt FinalExecutable.jar Combine.class
```

If `Combine` is declared in package `foo.bar`, then the above should be.

```
 echo Main-Class: foo.bar.Combine > manifest.txt 
 jar cmf manifest.txt FinalExecutable.jar foo/bar/Combine.class
```

and you need to be in the directory above the `foo` directory.

NB: the "Main-Class" attribute in the manifest must be a Java fully qualified class name, NOT a filename or file pathname.

It also should be noted that the `CLASSPATH` environment variable and the `-cp` argument will be ignored when you run a JAR using `java -jar ...`.  If your executable JAR depends on other JAR files, you should either combine them (to create a shaded JAR) or you should add a "Class-Path" attribute to the manifest; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Finally, my advice would be to use a build tool (e.g. Maven) to compile your code, create the executable JAR file, etc rather than doing it by hand.